# adding image in eclipse JFrame, dont know what im doing wrong

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Quiz extends JFrame implements ItemListener{

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/quiz.jpg"));
    JLabel lblimg = new JLabel(icon);
    //Image icon = createImageIcon("images/quiz.jpg");
    //raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
    public Quiz()
    {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(50, 50);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(lblimg);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Quiz();

    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: What specifically is going wrong? Have you tried making `this.setVisible(true)` the last call in your constructor?

Comment: yes I did set it visible @AndyDavies

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked whether you tried calling it last in the constructor after you've setup all your components.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. You need to add the images folder to the classpath and potentially remove the `/images/` from the path you provide

Comment: I added the image in my source folder in side my project @triadiktyo

Comment: Hi @lee That works because src is in your classpath. But having resources in you src folder is not good style. Its much cleaner to add the images folder or the project root to the classpath.

Comment: when I run it, it gives me this error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Quiz.<init>(Quiz.java:20)
 at Quiz.main(Quiz.java:69)'

Comment: Yes probably because your classpath is still not set correctly. Are you developing on eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Is your image wrapped in your JAR file? If your doing it this way, your image should be wrapped in your JAR/bin(in eclipse) file under the subfolder `images`

Hope this makes sense.